# C++ Relaying Member Functions in Nested Classes?

Tags: c++, class, nested

I work at a manufacturing plant that uses a large C++ project to automate the manufacturing process.

I see a certain practice all over the place that just seems to make code unnecessarily long and I was wondering if there is a specific reason this practice is used.

See below for a simplified example that demonstrates this practice.

First file:

```
class A {

private:
   int a;

public:
   int get_a()
   { return a; }

   void set_a(int arg)
   { a = arg; }
};
```

Second file:

```
class B {

private:
   int b;

public:
   int get_b()
   { return b; }

   void set_b(int arg)
   { b = arg; }
};
```

Third file:

```
class C {

private:
   A obj1;
   B obj2;

public:
   int get_a()
   { return obj1.get_a(); }

   int get_b()
   { return obj2.get_b(); }

   void set_a(int arg)
   { obj1.set_a(arg); }

   void set_b(int arg)
   { obj2.set_b(arg); }
};
```

It seems to me like a slight change in design philosophy could have drastically reduced the amount of code in the third file. Something like this:

```
class C {

public:
   A obj1;
   B obj2;

};
```

Having `obj1` and `obj2` be `public` members in the `C` class does not seem to be unsafe, because the `A` and `B` classes each safely handle the getting and setting of their own member variables.

The only disadvantage I can think of to doing it this way is that any instances of the `C` class that calls a function would need to do something like `obj.obj1.get_a()` instead of just `obj.get_a()` but this seems like much less of an inconvenience than having private `A` and `B` object instances in the `C` class and then manually needing to "relay" all of their member functions.

I realize for this simple example, it is not much extra code, but for this large project that my company uses, it adds literally *tens of thousands* of lines of code.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The getters and setters are a bit of a smell, but it looks like the original developer was applying the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). There are pros and cons to it.

Comment: The cons seem obvious - adding a ton of more code. What are the cons? (Besides what I already mentioned, i.e. `obj.obj1.get_a()` vs. `obj.get_a()`)

Comment: Nevermind... the Wikipedia page explains it pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just ask the people who wrote the code if they are still in the company? The question is legitimate, but there are hundreds of good reasons I can think of, so there's not much point in asking here at SO.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I thought of that, but most of the code was written over 10 years ago by a contracting company from another country. Even if I had a name of who wrote the code, there's no guarantee they work there anymore and even if they did, I doubt they would be eager to answer my questions. I wanted to ask on SO because I thought there could be a general reason why this is done, plus the community here is generally good at getting an answer fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many reasons. One is the following:

Imagine you write a function that does something with the member `a`. You want the same code to accept an `A` as well as a `C`. Your function could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t) {
    std::cout << " a = " << t.get_a();
}
```

This would not work with your `C` because it has a different interface.

Encapsulation has its benefits, but I agree with you that encapsulation for the sake of encapsulation very often leads to much more code and often to nothing else than that.

In general, forcing calling code to write something like `obj.obj1.get_a()` is discouraged, because it reveals implementations details. If you ever change e.g the type of `a` then your `C` has no control whatsoever on that change. On the other hand if in the origninal code `a` changes from `int` to `double` then `C` can decide whether to keep the `int` interface and do some conversion (if applicable) or to change its interface.

Comment: *In general, forcing calling code to write something like obj.obj1.get_a() is discouraged, because it reveals implementations details.* Wow, good point, never thought of it that way. It definitely makes the code that uses the C class a lot cleaner, just makes the C class itself seemingly have a lot of "overhead" type code. Anyway, your explanation here is great and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 btw the code in your post looks like what I was thaught in school and it took me many years to understand that given only that code there really is no single good reason to use getters and setters. I think it is important to know why following guidelines, because sometimes you dont want to follow it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It does add a little extra code, but the important thing is your interface.  A class has a responsibility, and the members it holds are implementation details.  If you expose internal objects and force users to "get the object, then make calls on it" you are coupling the caller to the implementation more than if you just provide an interface that does the job for the user.  As an analogy, [borrowed from wikipedia] when one wants a dog to walk, one does not command the dog's legs to walk directly; instead one commands the dog which then commands its own legs.

[Law of Demeter / Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

> More formally, the Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method m of an object O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of objects:

- O itself
- m's parameters
- Any objects created/instantiated within m
- O's direct component objects
- A global variable, accessible by O, in the scope of m

> In particular, an object should avoid invoking methods of a member object returned by another method. For many modern object oriented languages that use a dot as field identifier, the law can be stated simply as "use only one dot". That is, the code a.b.c.Method() breaks the law where a.b.Method() does not.